# error running pod install error launching application on iphone11 Pro Max

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I finished my flutter app, and i want to test it in ios device, so i used a mac laptop and i did all the installations but when i did the command "flutter run" i got this error 
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro Max in debug mode...

```
 Running pod install...                                              4,0s
 CocoaPods' output:
 ↳
  Preparing

Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)

Finding Podfile changes
  A flutter_barcode_scanner
  A geolocator
  A google_api_availability
  A google_maps_flutter
  A location
  A location_permissions
  A shared_preferences
  A shared_preferences_macos
  A shared_preferences_web
  - Flutter

Fetching external sources
-> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
-> Fetching podspec for `flutter_barcode_scanner` from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_barcode_scanner/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `geolocator` from `.symlinks/plugins/geolocator/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `google_api_availability` from `.symlinks/plugins/google_api_availability/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `google_maps_flutter` from `.symlinks/plugins/google_maps_flutter/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `location` from `.symlinks/plugins/location/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `location_permissions` from `.symlinks/plugins/location_permissions/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `shared_preferences` from `.symlinks/plugins/shared_preferences/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `shared_preferences_macos` from `.symlinks/plugins/shared_preferences_macos/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `shared_preferences_web` from `.symlinks/plugins/shared_preferences_web/ios`

Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
  CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "flutter_barcode_scanner":
  In Podfile:
    flutter_barcode_scanner (from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_barcode_scanner/ios`)

Specs satisfying the `flutter_barcode_scanner (from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_barcode_scanner/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:328:in `raise_error_unless_state'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:310:in `block in unwind_for_conflict'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:308:in `tap'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:308:in `unwind_for_conflict'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:684:in `attempt_to_activate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:254:in `process_topmost_state'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:986:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:984:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:410:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:234:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:233:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:156:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `<main>'

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max.
```

Comment: Check `flutter_barcode_scanner` plugin. I think its not installed properly. Open cmd inside project directory. `cd` into `ios` directory. Type `pod install` and then try `flutter run`. Let me know the result

Comment: when i run pod install i got thi error :iMac-de-imac-1D03-014:ios halima$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "flutter_barcode_scanner":
  In Podfile:
    flutter_barcode_scanner (from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_barcode_scanner/ios`)

Specs satisfying the `flutter_barcode_scanner (from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_barcode_scanner/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target

Comment: Try `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub get`. First dont forget to check your `flutter_barcode_scanner` package name is correct and the version is exist

Comment: If you are using M1 chip then answer is here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72751206/error-to-set-up-cocoapods-for-arm-macos-run-arch-x86-64-sudo-gem-install-ffi

Answer (score 17):

try this

```
rm ios/Podfile
flutter pub upgrade
flutter pub run
cd ios
pod init
pod update
flutter clean && flutter run
```

Comment: the flutter pub run step did not work but doing everything else did.  could not delete pod file from android studio, had to do it in finder (or terminal)

Comment: Doesn't work for me (mac m1 pro)

Answer (score 4):

### Flutter: Try this

1. Delete the `Podfile`, `Podfile.lock`, `Pods folder`, `Runner.xcworkspace`, `Flutter.framwork(in ios/Flutter folder)`
2. `flutter clean`
3. `flutter build ios`

Comment: project is working fine with flutter run command but its not working when hit run button directally ..

Answer (score 3):

For the m1 Mac I had a similar error for google mobile ads. The solution was that you have to download cocoa-pods from homebrew.
Follow The 2022 update: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65334677/16122154

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

The following works for me:

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
```

Comment: This one solved the issue, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Trust me, I search for over 5 hours, tried every solution I cound find on internet. And only one work:

1. Delete the Podfile, Podfile.lock, Pods folder
2. flutter clean
3. cd ios
4. pod deintegrate ( this way pod will not reinstall the old libray )
5. cd ../
6. flutter run

Most of the solution don't include step 4, so that why even you clean and reinstall pod, it still behave the same.

Comment: Nothing happened with this solution also. No use.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Flutter, in your pubspec.yaml file make sure that your dependencies are installed below the cupertino icons line with correct indentation or it'll throw an error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.15-catalina

Make your day happy thanks buddy for the help...

MacOS catalina has permission issues on pre installed ruby and rails.

rbenv is best version control thing.
You need to install this tool by using ***terminal***:

Open your terminal and type these commands:

```sh
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

And then run these commands:

```sh
brew install rbenv ruby-build

# Add rbenv to bash so that it loads every time you open a terminal
echo 'if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi' >> ~/.zshrc
source ~/.zshrc

# Install Ruby
rbenv install 2.7.1
rbenv global 2.7.1
ruby -v
now install pods by going to your ios folder in flutter project
cd ios 
pod install
```

That's it.