# Error "To set up CocoaPods for ARM macOS, run: arch -x86_64 sudo gem install ffi Unable to solve error"

Tags: flutter, firebase, android-studio, cocoapods

Cocoa pods error in Android Studio on M1 Mac in Flutter. Need help fixing this error. I have tried other methods online but none have helped. I have even re-installed with HomeBrew, but no help.

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.3, on macOS 12.2.1 21D62 darwin-arm (Rosetta),
    locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.4.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!

Error: To set up CocoaPods for ARM macOS, run:
  arch -x86_64 sudo gem install ffi

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 13.

dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle, 0x0009): tried: '/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/lib/ffi_c.bundle' (no such file) - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle (LoadError)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Run this commands in terminal

`arch -x86_64 sudo gem install ffi`

Then inside the ios folder of your project run this command

`arch -x86_64 pod install`

Comment: Thank you so much! This has really helped me and thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Hi i am getting the same error, but when i run arch -x86_64 pod install it says [!] No `Podfile' found in the project directory.

Comment: sorry just realize has to go to the ios folder