# Error: To set up CocoaPods for ARM macOS, run: arch -x86_64 sudo gem install ffi

Tags: installation, rubygems, cocoapods, sudo, ffi

Error: To set up CocoaPods for ARM macOS, run:
arch -x86_64 sudo gem install ffi

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.

Comment: Seems like duplication of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72751206/error-to-set-up-cocoapods-for-arm-macos-run-arch-x86-64-sudo-gem-install-ffi)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error "To set up CocoaPods for ARM macOS, run: arch -x86\_64 sudo gem install ffi Unable to solve error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72751206/error-to-set-up-cocoapods-for-arm-macos-run-arch-x86-64-sudo-gem-install-ffi)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like duplication [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72751206/error-to-set-up-cocoapods-for-arm-macos-run-arch-x86-64-sudo-gem-install-ffi)

Run this commands in terminal

```
arch -x86_64 sudo gem install ffi
```

Then inside the ios folder of your project run this command

```
arch -x86_64 pod install
```